# Django prefetch related no duplicates with intermediate table

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a question I am trying to solve for one day now.

With the models

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    ...

class Source(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40,unique=True)
    ...
```

I am trying to model the world of quotes. with relationships: one `Source` having many `Quote`s, one `Quote` having many `Tag`s. 
Problem is:

1. How do I get all `Tag`s that are contained in a `Source` (through the contained `Quote`s) ?
2. with the minimum possible queries.
3. with the amount of times they are contained in that source

I have tried the naive one with no prefetch related, with a model method

```
def source_tags(self):
    tags = Tag.objects.filter(quote__source__id=self.id).distinct().annotate(usage_count=Count('quote'))
    return sorted(tags, key=lambda tag:-tag.usage_count)
```

And in the template:

```
{% for tag in source.source_tags|slice:":5" %}
    source.quote
{% endfor %}
```

Now I have

```
sources = Source.objects.all().prefetch_related('quote_set__tags')
```

And in the template I have no idea how to iterate correctly to get the `Tag`s for one source, and how I would go about counting them instead of listing duplicate tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the result in a single SQL query:

```
# views.py
from django.db.models import Count
from .models import Source


def get_tag_count():
    """
    Returns the count of tags associated with each source
    """
    sources = Source.objects.annotate(tag_count=Count('quote__tags')) \
                         .values('title', 'quote__tags__name', 'tag_count') \
                         .order_by('title')
    # Groupe the results as
    # {source: {tag: count}}
    grouped = {}
    for source in sources:
        title = source['title']
        tag = source['quote__tags__name']
        count = source['tag_count']
        if not title in grouped:
            grouped[title] = {}
        grouped[title][tag] = count
    return grouped



# in template.html

{% for source, tags in sources.items %}

    <h3>{{ source }}</h3>

    {% for tag, count in tags.items %}
        {% if tag %}
            <p>{{ tag }} : {{ count }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Complementary tests :)

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Source, Tag, Quote
from .views import get_tag_count


class SourceTags(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        abc = Source.objects.create(title='ABC')
        xyz = Source.objects.create(title='XYZ')

        inspire = Tag.objects.create(name='Inspire', slug='inspire')
        lol = Tag.objects.create(name='lol', slug='lol')

        q1 = Quote.objects.create(text='I am inspired foo', source=abc)
        q2 = Quote.objects.create(text='I am inspired bar', source=abc)
        q3 = Quote.objects.create(text='I am lol bar', source=abc)
        q1.tags = [inspire]
        q2.tags = [inspire]
        q3.tags = [inspire, lol]
        q1.save(), q2.save(), q3.save()

    def test_count(self):
        # Ensure that only 1 SQL query is done
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            sources = get_tag_count()
            self.assertEqual(sources['ABC']['Inspire'], 3)
            self.assertEqual(sources['ABC']['lol'], 1)
```

I have basically used the [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) and [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) functions from the ORM. They are very powerful because they automatically perform the joins. They are also very efficient because they hit the database only once, and return only those fields which are specified.

Comment: i can not get it work in the intended way. the values list has each source value multiple times... ( at least {% for source in sources %} does not work ..), results are not grouped by sources anymore

Comment: For each Tag there is one entry in the values list. I think it is not easily possible withouth Q objects or prefetch related.

Comment: maybe the best way is to just cache the results as this seems a hard task... trying to get a mysql query now which i could maybe translate to django orm query with stackoverflow's help

Comment: I have updated the above view and tests to return the tags count in the dictionary {source: {tag: count}} . Thus each source will appear only once.

Comment: still not working as intended. as there is no list of tags in each source object

Comment: @user9 There are the tags, thier count as well as the source. You might be using it incorrectly in the template. I have included the template snippet in the above answer.

Comment: you know, the problem is that it only gives one tag per source, but a source can have multiple tags

Comment: @user9 No, it does give ***all*** the tags per source. **Can you provide the assertion tests where it fails?** or the template code you are using? I am sure there are some differences in what you are implementing. It is hard to debug without code.